# Intellij idea crashes when running a javafx app

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I have the latest version of intellij idea community 2023.3.1 my problem is as follows: I wanted to create a new javafx project using maven intellij idea generated the files for my project but as soon as I run it intellij quits unexpectedly then my javafx application runs normally my question why does intellij idea crash in this way?

I uninstalled intellij idea then installed it again, cleared the cache but the problem persist.

Comment: What operating system do you use? What version of IntelliJ do you use? This sounds very strange. Maybe it is better to ask Netbeans theirself about this topic: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Please provide the crash logs. Are there any events logged in the Windows Event Log when it happens? https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/ .

Are there any java_error_in_*.log files in the user home directory?

Are there any crash dumps (idea64.exe.dmp) files in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\ directory?